# Class cast Exception while trying to deploy the Modules in axis 2 : OS: Linux , Tomcat Version:8

Tags: apache-axis, classcastexception, tomcat8

When I am trying to start the tomcat, at the time of deploying the axis2 modules , I am getting **class cast exception**.

I have enabled the **EnableChildfirstClassLoading** property. When I checked the classloading(using -verbose), some of the classes are getting loaded twice.
e.g. `[Loaded org.apache.axis2.engine.MessageReceiver from file:/irv_test/cipsm/SecureLinkTestingNEW/SLInstaller1/app4.0/tomcat/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar]`

This class is loaded twice from the same jar location.

*Axis Version: 1.6.2

Tomcat: 8

OS: Redhat Linux*

***Here is the trace:***

> [ERROR] The soapmonitor-1.6.2.mar module, which is not valid, caused org.apache.axis2.handlers.soapmonitor.SOAPMonitorModule cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.modules.Module
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.handlers.soapmonitor.SOAPMonitorModule cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.modules.Module
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.readModuleArchive(ArchiveReader.java:527)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:77)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:69)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:64)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:158)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:228)
>       at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
>       at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.handlers.soapmonitor.SOAPMonitorModule cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.modules.Module
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.populateModule(ModuleBuilder.java:233)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.readModuleArchive(ArchiveReader.java:514)
>       ... 31 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.handlers.soapmonitor.SOAPMonitorModule cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.modules.Module
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.loadModuleClass(ModuleBuilder.java:86)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.populateModule(ModuleBuilder.java:121)
>       ... 32 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.handlers.soapmonitor.SOAPMonitorModule cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.modules.Module
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder$1.run(ModuleBuilder.java:76)
>       at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.loadModuleClass(ModuleBuilder.java:74)
>       ... 33 more`

Comment: can you please format it?

Comment: Formatted the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EnableChildFirstClassLoading` is broken in Axis2 1.6.2 and 1.6.3. See [AXIS2-5720](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5720).

Comment: Thanks a lot Andreas!! When I used the axis 1.7.0 deployment related class files, it worked fine for me.